# MVC3 and regex route parameters

Tags: regex, parameters, routes, asp.net-mvc-3

We are moving to MVC3 and we already have a complex url redirect/rewrite scheme in place.

We have [what I consider to be] complex urls that need to be decomposed to their component values.

For instance, the url http://web-current/billet-grilles/10a50164A.aspx, needs to have the 10 and the 50164 removed and passed as parameters.

The following is our existing regex:

```
([^/]+)/10[A|a]([0-9]+)[A|a]{0,1}.aspx[\?]*([^/]*)
```

I have tried this, but I run into issues:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Department", "{silo}/10[A|a}{departmentId}[A|a]{0,1}.aspx", new {controller = "Department", action = "Index"}, new {silo = ".*",  departmentId = "[0-9]+" })
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Your existing regex doesn't look so good, I'm guessing that you want something more like: `([^/]+)/10[Aa]([0-9]+)[Aa]?\.aspx(?:\?([^/]*))?`

Comment: Thanks, it turns out the regex is ok, it was the route processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a new route object from http://iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx.

This works perfectly, thanks